How to resolve "Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str' error"?
I tried to combine and sum 2 Excel by Python but when I used "for loop", I found an error "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'"
See my code below:
import pandas as pd
import os

os.getcwd() + '/projects'

all_bit = os.listdir(os.getcwd() + '/projects/Python_excel/Test_files')

#Read Excel Bitcoin 1
bitcoin1 = pd.read_excel(os.getcwd() + '/projects/Python_excel/Test_files/' + all_bit[0])

#Check file
all_bit[0]

#Change data types
bitcoin1["Latest"] = bitcoin1["Latest"].astype(int)
bitcoin1["Open"] = bitcoin1["Open"].astype(int)
bitcoin1["Highest"] = bitcoin1["Highest"].astype(int)
bitcoin1["Lowest"] = bitcoin1["Lowest"].astype(int)

#Drop unnecessary column
bitcoin1 = bitcoin1.drop(['%Change','Amount'], axis = 1, inplace = False)

#Read Excel Bitcoin 2
bitcoin2 = pd.read_excel(os.getcwd() + '/projects/Python_excel/Test_files/' + all_bit[1])

#Change data types
bitcoin2["Latest"] = bitcoin2["Latest"].astype(int)
bitcoin2["Open"] = bitcoin2["Open"].astype(int)
bitcoin2["Highest"] = bitcoin2["Highest"].astype(int)
bitcoin2["Lowest"] = bitcoin2["Lowest"].astype(int)

#Drop unnecessary column
bitcoin2 = bitcoin2.drop(['%Change','Amount'], axis = 1, inplace = False)

#Loop
rep = pd.DataFrame()
for bitcoin in all_bit:
    data_bit = pd.read_excel(os.getcwd() + '/projects/Python_excel/Test_files/' + bitcoin)
    rep = rep.add(data_bit.set_index('Date'),fill_value=0)

My error picture

After I finished my for loop, it showed "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'". I tried to change float to int but it not working.
Could you guys advise me?
Thank you

Please add the full traceback error message so that we can see which line failed.

You create bitcoin1 and bitcoin2, change their type, and then don't use them. You go back and read the originals again, don't change their type, and then have an error in the addition. It appears that there are some type problems in the files. Are there many files? Should you have done astype on the files you read in the for loop?

Now I added my error picture.
@tdelaney Yes, I tried to change the type to float. I have 2 same files and want to generate them for automated Excel. My original file is in all_bit but it is a list. I still find the way to add my change type file to "all_bit"

Can I export the file I changed type to the folder of "all_bit" and run it again?

Please add your error as text instead of as a picture

The excel files you loaded have their column values in string format and their length are different. df.add() method does the element-wise summing, and "fill_value=0" means if their length doesn't match fill the end of the shorter df with 0.0 so their length would match. That's why you get the error of adding str to float.
You have to first change values to numeric and then add the numbers but Bitcoin{1,2} are doing nothing for you since you don't use them later.
Here is the code to do the task for you:
import pandas as pd
import os

directory = os.getcwd() + '/projects/Python_excel/Test_files/'
result_df = pd.DataFrame()

for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
    df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(directory, file_name))

    # Convert 'Date' column to datetime and set it as index
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').drop(columns=["%Change", "Amount"], errors='ignore')
    result_df = result_df.add(df, fill_value=0)

print(result_df)


Thank you for your answer but when I use this code my 'Date' column cannot change to index, it shows as a numeric value. I want to change my 'Date' column to index.

Simply just convert the date column to datetime format and set it to index and do the rest. I'll update the code considering the new column.
